# Sharing MSE posts in other posts

Tags: discussion, specific-user, hyperlinks

When I want to share a post, I always first remove my user ID (the last number) from the link. Is this recommended or not? And why is my user ID there anyway?

[image]

Comment: I typically use the bookmarklet "Link" from here: http://web.archive.org/web/20180705103212/https://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/ Quote from that page: "When used on any webpage, generates a link to that page in the form [text](url). "Text" is the text selected on the page, or, if nothing is selected, the page title (<h1> element). On SE sites, shortens the link."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your user ID is there to keep track of how many users visit a link thanks to you sharing it; there is a series of badges for that, namely

- [Announcer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) for 25 unique visits
- [Booster](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) for 300
- [Publicist](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) for 1000

You can of course remove that ID when you don't want to expose your Mathematics Stack Exchange account to whomever you share the link with, or in the rare case that it's too long (e.g. in a lengthy comment).

Comment: I think someone evil like me can misuse from this option. Editing all shared links and add my User ID to it. HAHA.. (evil-smile:)

Comment: So, as per the description in the tag menu, it can be exploited by TOR....